# Can we distribute the file groups of a single database to reside on multiple servers?

Tags: sql-server, database, filegroup

We have a requirement to distribute the filegroups of one of our database on multiple servers. Can you please let me know if that is possible and if yes how can we do that?

We are using SQL server 2012 standard edition

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to that, on SQL Server, is SQL Server 2016/2017, where you can specify objects to store in Azure.  i.e. a hybrid.   some objects stored in .?df files on your disks, and some in azure.

See:
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/06/09/sql-server-2016-use-sql-server-2016-stretch-database-notes-field-127/